# Google sheets to salesforce

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to connect data in google sheet to salesforce

```
function onEdit(e){
  SendtoSalesforce();

}

function SendtoSalesforce() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var ldap = sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue();
  var firstname = sheet.getRange(row,5).getValue();
  var lastname = sheet.getRange(row,6).getValue();
  var company = sheet.getRange(row,3).getValue();
  var companyurl = sheet.getRange(row,4).getValue();
  var email = sheet.getRange(row,8).getValue();
  var title = sheet.getRange(row,7).getValue();
  var resp = UrlFetchApp
      .fetch(
          'https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8',
          {
            method: 'post',
            payload: {
               'oid' : 'xxxxxxxxx',     //salesforce organization id 
              'Ldap_c' : ldap,
              'first_name' : firstname,            //lead field firstname 
              'last_name' : lastname,                    //lead field name last name
              'email' : email,                         //lead field name email
              'company' : company, 
              'Website' : companyurl,
              'Contact_Title_Role__c': title
}
          });

  Logger.log(resp.getContentText());
}
```

Error
You do not have permission to call UrlFetchApp.fetch. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
    at SendtoSalesforce(Code:16)
    at onEdit(Code:2)

Comment: If you want to run the script by the OnEdit event trigger, how about trying [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)?

Comment: To build on @Tanaike 's suggestion, using simple triggers (i.e. having them declared in the code itself) runs with different permissions, your `onEdit()` will not have permissions for some tools (like `UrlFetchApp.fetch`). Installable Triggers should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I just opened the related [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) for `UrlFetchApp`.

It contains the following paragraph:

> Scripts that use this method require authorization with one or more of the following scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request

You might need to configure a scope in `oauthScopes` [as shown here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes).

I hope this helps!